# SVG animation using javascript not working in firefox

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, svg

I'm struggling with something that should be easy, let me explain :

- I have a SVG using the animateTransform tag I use JavaScript to
  change the form attribut
- then I use the beginElement()

The SVG

```
<svg version="1.2" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%">
    <defs>
        <path id="right" fill="#F7931E" d="M55.002,30c0-13.808-11.192-25-25-25v6c10.477,0,19,8.523,19,19s-8.523,19-19,19v6 C43.81,55,55.002,43.808,55.002,30z">
            <animateTransform id="rotate" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 30 30" to="180 30 30" begin="0s"  fill="freeze"/>
        </path>

        <path id="left" fill="#F7931E" d="M11.002,30c0-10.477,8.523-19,19-19V5c-13.808,0-25,11.192-25,25s11.192,25,25,25v-6 C19.526,49,11.002,40.477,11.002,30z">
            <animateTransform  id="rotate2" attributeName="transform" type="rotate" from="0 30 30" to="180 30 30" begin="0s"   fill="freeze"/>
        </path>

        <mask id="hide-left">
            <rect x="0" y="0" width="30" height="60" fill="white"/>
        </mask>

        <mask id="hide-right">
            <rect id="super" x="30" y="0" width="30" height="60" fill="white"/>
        </mask>
    </defs>

    <!-- Layout -->
    <use xlink:href="#right" mask="url(#hide-right)"/>
    <use xlink:href="#left" mask="url(#hide-left)"/>
</svg>
```

The JS

```
    var updateCircle= function (pourcentage) {

    if (pourcentage < 0.5) {
        var angle = pourcentage * 2;
        var angle_vert = 180 * angle;
        var angle_rouge = 0;
    }
    else {
        var angle_vert = 180;
        var angle = (1 - pourcentage) * 2;
        var angle_rouge = 180 - (180 * angle);
    }
    $("#mod_countdown #right #rotate").attr('from', angle_vert + ' 30 30');
    $("#mod_countdown #left #rotate2").attr('from', angle_rouge + ' 30 30');
    $("#mod_countdown #right #rotate")[0].beginElement();
    $("#mod_countdown #left #rotate2")[0].beginElement();
};
```

The example to play with : http://jsfiddle.net/oandcf08/2/

My problem is : it's not working on firefox and I don't know why...

**[edit]**

Fun fact : when I add the attribute transform :  `<path transform="scale(5)" ...` it's working in firefox check it out : http://jsfiddle.net/oandcf08/3/ , it's working but I don't understand why and it don't seem to be a reliable workaround

Comment: It's a known issue with SMIL and `<use>` elements https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=738574

Comment: when I don't use the <use></use> the circle is not showing in firefox

Comment: I'd need to see what you've changed if you want me to comment on why that is.

Comment: So if we can't use the <use></use> what is the workaround ? please see my edit

Comment: As a side note, in Chrome when the circle finishes it's first "cycle" it starts again from the bottom rather than the top of the circle

Comment: @Jocie Yea, it's because I don't reset the timer  when it's done. but that's not the issue, in my app it's working properly.

Comment: Fair enough, I just wanted to raise it in case you'd not spotted it! I always think it's better to say these things and it already be known than keep quiet and it get missed.

Comment: Use just creates copies of things so write the stuff `<use>` is pointing to inline in the code.